# Assign a new role in Entrust

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, user-roles

As part of my 'approval' process, I want the admin to allocate users different roles, on demand.

I want to 'detach' the user's current role and add a new one.

```
$id = Input::get('submit');
$user = User::where('id','=', $id)->first();
$user->attachRole(2);

$user->save();
```

The code above gets the user's ID that I want to reassign a role to, and then the attachRole, assigned the new one, but I can't delete the previous one.

However, it doesn't remove the user's previous role it was assigned to.

```
$user->detachRole(USER ID HERE);
```

doesn't seem to work.

The only problem is, if it was in the 'Role' table, I could possibly use $user->roles()->delete (something like that), where has the assignment of users to roles is in the 'assigned_roles' table.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example function which you could use to save your roles, it accepts an array of role id's:

```
 /**
 * Save roles inputted from multiselect
 * @param $inputRoles
 */
public function saveRoles($inputRoles)
{
    if(! empty($inputRoles)) {
        $this->roles()->sync($inputRoles);
    } else {
        $this->roles()->detach();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, John! Finally, I've stopped losing sleep.